# How to construct a bijection from [a, b] to (0,1)?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

The question is how to construct a bijection between [2, 4] and (0, 1), but is there a general formula to do so?

Comment: All that’s required is a minor adaptation of the first answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006445/proving-0-1-and-0-1-have-the-same-cardinality?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Yeah I understand the solution for both [0, 1] to (0, 1] and from [0, 1] to (0, 1) but somehow I don't seem to find that minor adaptation

Comment: Just compose with a bijection between $[a,b]$ and $[0,1]$: the linear function that takes $0$ to $a$ and $1$ to $b$ is the simplest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend first solving these two simpler problems:

1. Find a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1]$.
2. Find a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$.

Problem (1) already contains the essential new difficulty of this set of problems. Problem (2) is a chance to double-down on the new idea from the solution to problem (1), and should lead pretty nicely to a solution to your original problem.

One way to go from problem (2) to your exact problem is to find a bijection between $[2,4]$ and $[0,1]$ (which should be easy, with a continuous function) and then compose the two bijections together.

Comment: In (2), do you mean $(0,1]$ and $(0,1)$?

Comment: Yeah I understand the solution for both [0, 1] to (0, 1] and from [0, 1] to (0, 1) but somehow I don't seem to find that minor adaptation that's needed here. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I added another sentence to address this. By the way, the remarks in your comment are really great things to include in the question statement to begin with; providing that context is important for people's feedback to be aimed at the part of the problem that you actually want help with.