# Countability of Infinite Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Show that $|\mathbb{R}|$=$|[0,1]|$.

If we were to find a function whose domain is $\mathbb{R}$ and range is $[0,1]$ and show it is a bijection, then we can show that this is true. The function that I came up with is $f(x)=\frac{\arctan x+\frac{\pi}{2}}{\pi}$, but this function's range is $(0,1)$. Is there a function that would work?

Comment: What does the title "countability of finite sets" have to do with your question about finding a bijection between two uncountable infinite sets??

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213391/how-to-construct-a-bijection-from-0-1-to-0-1) and the questions it is a duplicate of for $(0,1) \sim [0,1]$

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use what you have and find a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$, then compose the two bijections to get what you need.  That question has been asked before.  A simple one $[0,1]$ to $(0,1]$ is $$f(x)=\begin {cases}
\frac 15&x=0\\ \frac 1{5^{n+1}}&x=\frac 1{5^n}\\x&\text{otherwise} \end {cases}$$  Basically you just push the extra point down the line.  You can do the same from the other end to take care of $1$.  You get used to ignoring stray points when you have a bijection between infinite sets, as you can always absorb them.

Answer (score 1):

Having $|(0,1)|=|\mathbb R|$ as showed by you is already sufficient, because notice that
$$(0,1) \subseteq [0,1] \subseteq \mathbb R$$
Thus there exist injection mapping $f(x)=x$ for those sets, which means:
$$|(0,1)| \le |[0,1]| \le |\mathbb R|$$
So it has to be the case that
$$|(0,1)| = |[0,1]|=|\mathbb R|$$

This is thanks to  [Cantor-Bernstein Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem)

Answer (score -1):

Send $0 \to 0$ and consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Then $(0,1) \to (1, \infty)$. Try to construct $g$ based on $f$ that satisfies your requirements. You will need translations and scaling.