# Intervals in the real numbers and cardinality - are they infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bijection between an open and a closed interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28568/bijection-between-an-open-and-a-closed-interval)

I'm a little confused, maybe i'm over thinking something so basic. But a closed interval [a,b] of real numbers has an infinite number of elements, correct? And the same goes for (a,b)? Then, [a,b] has the same cardinality as (a,b)?

Thanks.

Comment: Not if $a=b{}{}$

Comment: Yes, you are correct (provided a < b).  But "infinite" is a bit of an understatement: they each have uncountably many elements. (i.e. there are countably infinite ($\mathbb{Z}$) sets and uncountably infinite (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$) sets.  Each of the intervals you give have the same cardinality as the set of Reals.

Comment: All of your statements are correct provided that $a<b$.

Comment: This is at least one amongst a myriad of duplicates.

Comment: Thank you. I was a little confused because my instructor said "finite intervals" when describing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they have same cardinality. For convenience, here is a bijection $[0,1]\to[0,1)$:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{n+1}&\text{if }x=\frac1n\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb N\\x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then

$$g(x)=f(1-f(x))$$
is a bijection $[0,1]\to(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just as the integers greater than 0 have the same cardinality as the integers greater than 1.  Deleting a finite number of elements from any infinite set doesn't change its cardinality.  In this case we can find an explicit bijection.  Define $f(x): [0,1) \to (0,1)$ as follows:
If $x \ne 0, \frac 1{3^k}, f(x)=x \\ f(0)=\frac 13 \\f(\frac 1{3^k})=\frac 1{3^{k+1}}$

You can do the same at the other end.