# help "building Bijection functions" strategy

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am studying Discrete math at the moment and having trouble
finding bijections and building functions.. 
two problems for example:
$$[2, 5) \to (4, \infty)$$
and another example:
$$[0,1] \to (0,1)$$

Is there a good strategy?
thanx...

Comment: This is subtle. Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28568/bijection-between-an-open-and-a-closed-interval

Answer (score 2):

The idea: to get rid of the problematic extra (border) points take countable subsets of the unproblematic open intervals and use the trick of the [Hilbert's  Hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel).
Example:

$$f:[0,1)\longrightarrow(0,1)$$
$f(x) = x$ except for:
$$f(0)=1/2,$$
$$f(1/n)=1/(n+1),$$

Comment: [2,5)→(4,∞) how about this problem? the strategy does not seem to work for harder problems... im lost :(

Comment: @ItamarSilverstein, can you find a bijection between $(2,5)$ and $(4,\infty)$? Between $(0,1)$ and $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: @ItamarSilverstein, example: $x\to 1/x$ is a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: so how do you find [2,5)→(4,∞) ? I still can't see that.... not everyone is a genius,,,

Comment: @ItamarSilverstein, $x\mapsto 3+1/x$ is a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(4,\infty)$. Can you continue?

Comment: @ItamarSilverstein, do a chain of bijections between open intervals.

Comment: but math is about finding algorithms. can you give me strong alogrithms for find that? for example. in this particular example you examine the function 1/x and get that 1/x + 3 is mapping (0,1) to (4, ∞), but what is the next step? you need to find a bijection [2, 5) to (0, 1), what is the intuition?

Comment: Math is about solving problems, and for some of them there is no algorithm. However, we have the ability to recognize patterns and develop intuitions and successful strategies. Any bounded interval $(a,b)$ is can be bijected with another bounded interval $(c,d)$ by a linear function. Knowing a bijection $(0,1) \to (1,+\infty)$ gives you bijections between $(0,1)$ and $(-\infty, a)$ and $(b,+\infty)$, any $a,b$. So now you can show that there's a bijection between any two open intervals, bounded or unbounded. It remains to know bijections between $(0,1), (0,1], [0,1), [0,1]$.