# Existence of Continuous bijective function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I was looking for examples of bijective continuous functions infollowing cases

1. Does there exist Bijective continuous function $(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Yes, $f(x)=\frac{2x-1}{x-x^2}$

2. Does there exist Bijective continuous function from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow  (0,1)$ ?

Yes, as $(0,1) and \mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic so inverse of $f(x)$ defined above will be example such a function.

3. Does there exist a bijective continuous function from $[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

I think No, as continuous image of compact set is not compact.

4. Does there exist a bijective continuous function from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow  [a,b])$ ?

For this clearly it can be seen

a) continuous image of connected set is connected.

b) Inverse image of closed set under continuous map is closed.

So there exist such a function but i can not construct it.

5. Does  Does there exist a bijective continuous function from $ (a,b)  \rightarrow  [a,b])$?

No. as inverse image of closed set is not closed so there can not exist any continuous bijective function.

But as $(a,b)$ is  homeomorphic  to $\mathbb{R}$So if we construct a function $\mathbb{R \rightarrow}  [a,b]$ will that function work as an example of a function $ (a,b)  \rightarrow  [a,b])$?

6. Does  Does there exist a bijective continuous function from $ [a,b] \rightarrow  (a,b))$?

No. as inverse image of open set is not open so there can not exist any continuous bijective function.

Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere .And give examples of $(4)$ if any exists. Thanx very much for your time

Comment: I've always thought of Probability distributions being from R to [0,1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4. No. Suppose there exists such a function $f$. Say $f(x_0) = a$, then $f(x) > a$ for both $x<x_0$ and $x> x_0$, in contradiction with $f$ being a bijection.

5 and 6. Your arguments are invalid. Given continuous function $f:X\to Y$, the pre-image of an open(closed) set in $Y$ under $f$ is open(closed) in $X$. Here $(a,b)$ is indeed closed in $(a,b)$, and $[a,b]$ likewise. That no continuous function maps $[a,b]$ onto $(a,b)$ can be easily seen by noticing that $[a,b]$ is compact while $(a,b)$ isn't. That no continuous bijection maps $(a,b)$ to $[a,b]$ can be reasoned similarly as in 4.

Also be aware that in general a continuous bijection doesn't have to be a homeomorphism, so you probably want to refine your arguments in 2. That said, we do have [invariance of domain theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) in Euclidean spaces.

Comment: Thanx. I get your reasoning for 4. 5 and 6. But what if left the condition of continuity then can we find a bijective function in all cases? It seems yes to me

Comment: Yes. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28568/bijection-between-an-open-and-a-closed-interval, for example. There should be many answers on this site.

Comment: ok  I was unaware of Invariance of domain theorem. Now with the help of this i can directly say $f^{-1}$ is continuous as $(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Now if we left the condition of bijection then identity function will be example of (3) and can we find example for (4  )

Comment: Constant functions. Or if you want surjection, let $f$ be identity on $[a,b]$, $f(x) = a$ for $x<a$, $f(x) = b$ for $x>b$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed $f$ for (1) is not a bijection. One that is:

$f(x)=\tan(\pi x-\frac{\pi}{2})$

Crucially, any such $f$ must be monotone (in-fact it cannot have derivative 0 over any interval, only at single points) (why?)

For (2), just invert (the corrected) function for #1.

(3) is no because $[a,b]$ is compact, but $\mathbb{R}$ is not (cannot satisfy surjectivity and continuity at the same time for reason you gave).

(4) is also no, but the reasoning is slightly different (see @QiyuWen's answer).

(5) You're reasoning is wrong, it's for the same reason as in (4) (this has to do w/ monotonicity again).

(6) Appeal to compactness again ($(a,b)$ is not compact; why?).

Comment: As an additional comment: $(a,b)$ is open but not closed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but as a subset of itself (under the induced subspace topology), $(a,b)$ is *both* open and closed (the entire space is always both open and closed, same for the empty set). This is an important subtlety which comes from the definition of subspace topology: The subspace topology on any $S\in X$, $X$ a topological space, is formed by taking the intersection of each open set of $X$ with $S$ to form the open sets of $S$.