# Let's give a bijection between $ \{ x \in \mathbb{R}: 2 \ge x \ge 1 \} $ and $\mathbb{R} $

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can I maybe use in some way Hilbert's Grand Hotel Paradox or in which way can I find such a bijection?

Comment: Any reason not to use the more typical $1 \le x \le 2$ ?

Comment: Do you want an explicit bijection or just proof of a bijection?

Comment: I would like to find an explicit bijection, the exercise is using this notation $ 2 \ge x \ge 1 $

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb{R}$ bijects with $(0,1)$ via a scaled and translated $\tan$ function, so you're effectively looking for a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$. See [Bijection between an open and a closed interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28568/bijection-between-an-open-and-a-closed-interval?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: could you maybe give me some more hints?

Comment: Pick two sequences one from $0$ toward $1/2$ (increasing) and the other from $1$ toward $1/2$ (decreasing) neither sequence containing $1/2.$ Then on these "shift toward $1/2$ by one step", and use the identity map on the rest.