# Show the following for $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ is sigmoid function. Clearly $f(x)$ is bijective

Show that for an arbitrary interval $(a,b)$, by using the composition of $f$ with an appropriate function $g: (0,1) \to (a,b)$, show that $|\mathbb{R}|=|(a,b)|$ and use this to prove that $[a,b]\approx(a,b)$

This is an exercise in my book. But I couldnt solve it. Please help

Edited:

Considering $g: (0,1) \to (a,b), $  $g(x)=(b-a)x+a$ this function is bijective. So $gof$ is also bijective. So can we say that his shows $|\mathbb{R}|=|(a,b)|$

For the second part  I think we need a function lets say $h$ such that $h:[a,b]→(a,b)$ is a bijection.

Comment: Note that $f$ is a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Gary can you please elaborate what this gives and how to proceed next ?

Comment: Take $g(x) = (b - a)x + a$. This is a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(a,b)$. What can you say about $g(f(x))$?

Comment: @Gary so using $g(x)$ you proposed we have $g(f(x))=\dfrac{b-a}{1+e^{-x}}+a$

Comment: @Gary as $f$ and $g$ are bijection so $gof$ will be bijection as well. so can we say that this shows $|\mathbb{R}| =|(a,b)|$

Comment: @Gary for the second part I think we need a function lets say $h$ such that $h: [a,b] \to (a,b)$ is a bijection.

Comment: Your answer to the first part is correct. For the second part, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28570

Comment: @Gary Thank you..